# Python - Transform a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries as follows `[{Key:key, Value:value}]`, the keys are always literally "Key" and "Value" which must become a list of dictionaries `[{key:value}]`. I know how to do this with a for loop but was wondering if I can do it in a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[{d['Key']: d['Value']} for d in list_of_dicts]
```

Comment: That's awesome, so simple! Thanks